# How can I access the data inside the json

Tags: php, json, flutter

This is my data from the JSON file.

```
[
    {
        "id": "5",
        "msg": {
            "msg": "2121222",
            "sign": "אלמוג שטרית",
            "time": "26/6/2020 16:52",
            "title": "1212"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "4",
        "msg": {
            "msg": "דשחדש",
            "sign": "אלמוג שטרית",
            "time": " ",
            "title": "בדיקה נ"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "msg": {
            "msg": "21",
            "sign": "אלמוג שטרית",
            "time": "",
            "title": "בדיקה חדשה"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "msg": {
            "msg": "בדיקה חדשה",
            "sign": "אלמוג שטרית",
            "time": "",
            "title": "בדיקה חדשה"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "1",
        "msg": {
            "msg": "בדיקה",
            "sign": "",
            "time": "",
            "title": "בדיקה"
        }
    }
]
```

I extract this data from what database using PHP.
php code :

```
$stm = $conn->prepare($query);
$stm->execute();
$rows = $stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$js = json_encode($rows, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
print $js;
```

My question is how I can access the data contained within the "msg" example into "title".

My code on flutter is:

```
List data;

  Future<String> getData() async {
    var response = await http.get(
        Uri.encodeFull("*myUrl*"),
        headers: {
          "Accept": "application/json"
        }
    );

    this.setState(() {
      data = json.decode(response.body);
    });

    print(data[0]["title"]);

    return "Success!";
  }
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this line: print(data[0]["title"]); should be written like this: print(data[0].title);

Comment: Try `print(data[0]['msg']['title']);` This must print 1212

Answer (score 1):

Just check out this example :

```
[
    {
        "id": "5",
        "msg": {
            "msg": "2121222",
            "sign": "אלמוג שטרית",
            "time": "26/6/2020 16:52",
            "title": "1212"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "4",
        "msg": {
            "msg": "דשחדש",
            "sign": "אלמוג שטרית",
            "time": " ",
            "title": "בדיקה נ"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "msg": {
            "msg": "21",
            "sign": "אלמוג שטרית",
            "time": "",
            "title": "בדיקה חדשה"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "msg": {
            "msg": "בדיקה חדשה",
            "sign": "אלמוג שטרית",
            "time": "",
            "title": "בדיקה חדשה"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "1",
        "msg": {
            "msg": "בדיקה",
            "sign": "",
            "time": "",
            "title": "בדיקה"
        }
    }
]
```

Following is the model class for the json you provided.

```
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final yourModel = yourModelFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

List<YourModel> yourModelFromJson(String str) => List<YourModel>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => YourModel.fromJson(x)));

String yourModelToJson(List<YourModel> data) => json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));

class YourModel {
    YourModel({
        this.id,
        this.msg,
    });

    String id;
    Msg msg;

    factory YourModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => YourModel(
        id: json["id"],
        msg: Msg.fromJson(json["msg"]),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "msg": msg.toJson(),
    };
}

class Msg {
    Msg({
        this.msg,
        this.sign,
        this.time,
        this.title,
    });

    String msg;
    String sign;
    String time;
    String title;

    factory Msg.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Msg(
        msg: json["msg"],
        sign: json["sign"],
        time: json["time"],
        title: json["title"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "msg": msg,
        "sign": sign,
        "time": time,
        "title": title,
    };
}
```

This is the main ui

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:json_parsing_example/models.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  bool _isLoading = false;
  List<YourModel> yourModel = List();

  Future<String> loadFromAssets() async {
    return await rootBundle.loadString('json/parse.json');
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    dataLoadFunction();
  }

  dataLoadFunction() async {
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = true;
    });

  /*   String jsonString = await loadFromAssets();
    // i have locally addded the data using the json file you can fetch the api over here.
    final yourdataModel = yourModelFromJson(jsonString);
    yourModel = yourdataModel;

    Instead of this you can use the below as the above is the sample example that i have created for you

    
     */


     /* 
     This is what you should do just add the url and its done.

      var response = await http.get(
        Uri.encodeFull("*myUrl*"),
        headers: {
          "Accept": "application/json"
        }
    );

     final yourdataModel = yourModelFromJson(response.body);
      yourModel = yourdataModel; 
     
      //just uncomment this code and add the url you are good to go.


    */

    setState(() {
      _isLoading = false;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: _isLoading
            ? CircularProgressIndicator()
            : ListView.builder(
                itemCount: yourModel.length,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return Card(
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, left: 15),
                          child: Row(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Text('Message :'),
                              Text(yourModel[index].msg.msg),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        Divider(
                          color: Colors.grey,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Just check out the example and let me know if it works.

Comment: First of all thank you very much !!
Sorry I kinda don't understand I'm pretty new to flutter but how do I put the api link?

Comment: I have just updated the code just check it out and let me know  if you have any problem

Comment: just make  a checkmark so that it would be helpful for others.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
print(data['msg']['title'].toString());
```

Or this: (In Case if above Jason Data isn't a List)

```
print(data[0]['msg']['title'].toString());
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer. But I get the following error message: "Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'"

Comment: Okay, I tried but without success. I did instead: print (json.decode (data [0] ['msg']));
It just printed the data to me just how does decode do all the data in msg?